# Low contrast of post titles are making them hard to read

Tags: feature-request, design

The color #3FABC4 of post titles is very difficult to read against a white background. It only produces a contrast ratio of 2.68:1. Can we use a darker color, that is easier on the eyes?

[image]

Comment: Or, better put perhaps, this should be on meta.stackexchange.com

Comment: @BryanKrause: This colour is specific to this site’s design. (And even if it weren’t, SE policy is that you can post general problems on every per-site meta.)

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Thanks, didn't realize that particular color was different here than elsewhere.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft - fair enough, but it might be worthwhile bringing it up on Meta since readability issues should be made obvious to all sites.

Comment: @JonCuster: On Meta SE this will almost certainly be closed for being specific to a particular site.

Comment: Good question, lets hope we get an answer from the moderators soon.

Comment: @user111388: We moderators cannot do much about it, except forwarding it to SE staff, in case there appears to be sufficient demand for fixing this (in particular indicated by upvotes). Right now, this doesn’t appear to be the case.